# Querys in graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I'm trying to make a query with graphql to get a list of friends of one user finding by id.

My Mongodb is a multiple collection of:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c09af1ebaa7a16d74d52494"),
  "name": "zaraza",
  "surname": "zaraza",
  "email": "zaraza@gamil.com",
  "state": "Disponible",
  "__v": 0,
  "avatar": "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-380-456332.png",
  "ip": "",
  "friends": [
    {
      "_id": "5c09af05baa7a16d74d52493"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c09af32baa7a16d74d52495"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c09af45baa7a16d74d52496"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5"
    }
  ]
}
```

My graphql query is:

```
query {
  singleUser(
    _id: "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5"
  ){
    _id
    name
    surname
    email
    state
    avatar
    friends{
      _id
    }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to query a _id of "friends" array to complete my result with the name of each _id friend

With the last code I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "singleUser": {
      "_id": "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5",
      "name": "zaraza",
      "surname": "zaraza",
      "email": "zaraza@gamil.com",
      "state": "Disponible",
      "avatar": "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-373-456325.png",
      "friends": [
        {
          "_id": "5c09af32baa7a16d74d52495"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5c09af45baa7a16d74d52496"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I want get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "singleUser": {
      "_id": "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5",
      "name": "zaraza",
      "surname": "zaraza",
      "email": "zaraza@gamil.com",
      "state": "Disponible",
      "avatar": "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-373-456325.png",
      "friends": [
        {
          "_id": "5c09af32baa7a16d74d52495"
          **"name": "zaraza2"**
        },
        {
          "_id": "5c09af45baa7a16d74d52496"
          **"name": "zaraza3"**
        },
        {
          "_id": "5c09afda583b656e6d350dd5"
          **"name": "zaraza4"**
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The field name is get in the same collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `resolver` you can define functions to resolve specific fields.

We will define a function on the `User Type` to resolve the `friends` field.

```
const resolver = {
  // This is the type
  User: {
    // when we query friends field on the User type, run this function
    // first argument is the parent doc which we will use to 
    // extract the friends ids
    friends: parent => User.find({ _id: { $in: parent.friends } }, { name: 1 }) 
  }
};
```